# Generate Row number Automatically if only one Record is fetching

Tags: numbers, row

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SerailNo_LoadValue]
 (
@SerialNo int,
@Season nchar(5)
 )

AS

BEGIN
 IF  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MATERIAL_Stock WHERE SerialNo = @SerialNo and Season = @Season)

BEGIN
  if(@Season = 'PER')
  BEGIN

SELECT material_code,ULC_id,setNo,MONTH(GETDATE())AS Delivery_Month,YEAR(GETDATE())AS Delivery_Year,1 AS NORECORD
  ,ISNULL(qty_total,0) AS qty_total,ISNULL(ULC,0) AS 'ulsmtr',isnull(MATNR,'') as MATNR --ADDED BY LALIT AS DISCUSSED WITH DIPENDRA ON 22 APRIL 2016
  FROM MATERIAL_Stock LEFT JOIN ULC_master ON ULC_master.ID =MATERIAL_Stock.ULC_id  WHERE SerialNo = @SerialNo and Season = @Season

END
  ELSE

BEGIN

SELECT material_code,ULC_id,setNo,Delivery_Month,Delivery_Year,1 AS NORECORD
  ,ISNULL(qty_total,0) AS qty_total,ISNULL(ULC,0) AS 'ulsmtr',isnull(MATNR,'') as MATNR --ADDED BY LALIT AS DISCUSSED WITH DIPENDRA ON 22 APRIL 2016
  FROM MATERIAL_Stock LEFT JOIN ULC_master ON ULC_master.ID =MATERIAL_Stock.ULC_id  WHERE SerialNo = @SerialNo and Season = @Season

END

select distinct  Delivery_Year, Delivery_Month,  Season into #T from Material_stock 
where Season=@Season
order by Delivery_Year,Delivery_Month

select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Delivery_Year,Delivery_Month) AS RowNumber into #TT from #T

declare @MONTH int
declare @YEAR int
declare @ROWID int
select top 1 @MONTH=Delivery_Month,@YEAR=Delivery_Year from dbo.Material_stock where Season=@Season And SerialNo=@SerialNo
select @ROWID=RowNumber from #TT where Delivery_Month=@MONTH and Delivery_Year=@YEAR
select Delivery_Year as Delivery_Month1 , Delivery_Month, Delivery_Year, Season,RowNumber from #TT where RowNumber>=@ROWID

drop table #T
drop table #TT

END

END

Comment: Some times only one Record is fetching or sometimes three Record is fetchin

Comment: You've forgot to add a question.